# Running multiple Django sites on Windows in Virtual Host

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I have downloaded and installed [Django Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/django) which has Apache, Python and Django. During installation itself setup created a sample project which I configured it to run on `one.local.com(127.0.0.1)` and then I created another project to run on `two.local.com(127.0.0.1)`.

**.../Two/wsgi.py**

```
import os, sys

os.environ["PYTHON_EGG_CACHE"] = ".../Two/egg_cache"
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "Two.settings"

sys.path.append('.../Two') # I'm getting internal server error without this

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**.../One/wsgi.py**

```
import os, sys

os.environ["PYTHON_EGG_CACHE"] = ".../One/egg_cache"
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "One.settings"

sys.path.append('.../One') # I'm getting internal server error without this

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And everything seems to be working fine on Apache side but all site uses the same settings of [whichever happens to run first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration).

Below is the Apache config that I used.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName two.local.com
    ServerAlias two.local.com

    <Directory ".../Two">
        Options +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

    Alias /static ".../python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"
    WSGIScriptAlias / '.../Two/wsgi.py'

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName one.local.com
    ServerAlias one.local.com
    ...
    WSGIScriptAlias / '.../One/wsgi.py'
</VirtualHost>
```

I have already spent a lot of time trying to fix this but I don't know what I'm missing here. So, it will be a great help if anyone answer this.

***Brief of problem:***

Django is serving two different sites the same content based up on the settings of the site that I open first.

***Solution required:***

1. To fix the above mentioned problem
2. Run using different virtualenv
   (WSGIDaemonProcess is not supported in windows)

Comment: Hi, can you make your problem/question clearer? What is currently happening that is wrong? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Django serving two different sites the same content based up on the settings of the site that I open first.

Comment: do not use the environement to retrieve the settings, use your module directly, there is only on environnement in this context